# Within a cloud function, is it better to do 2 reads of one value each or 1 read that has around 20 fields?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a user object that contains more or less 20 different fields and amongst them are the classic `firstName` and `lastName`.

I was wondering, in terms of performance, what was the best thing to do if I wanted to get the `firstName` and `lastName` fields.

- do 2 reads to `users/user_id/firstName` and `users/user_id/lastName`
- do 1 read to `users/user_id` and grab everything even if I just need 2 fields

The first one will retrieve only the data that I need but will make 2 "network" calls between the cloud function servers and the realtime database servers while the 2nd one only 1 call.

I wonder if the calls between 2 two servers can be neglected as it's really fast or not.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the fields in the "full record" are large (100KB+) the performance differences between the options will likely be negligible and you should prefer the simpler solution, which is likely a single fetch of the entire record. Technically, the full record might incur a greater transfer cost, but even this is not certain since every request/response has overhead.